# Identificar e arquivar registros antigos de MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou trabalhando em um projeto usando banco de dados em `MySql` onde algumas áreas serão constantemente alimentadas gerando um número elevado de registros em pouco tempo, como é o caso de uma área para tickets de manutenção. Porém, esses dados se tornam obsoletos com a mesma rapidez com que são criados e, após um certo tempo, já não precisam mais ser usados.

Como posso montar um sistema para "Arquivar" esses registros de modo que ele não fique mais 'pesando' na tabela?

Atualmente tenho uma estrutura de tabelas relacionadas, onde relaciono clientes e moderadores com o Ticket. Exemplo:

```
tabela: Cliente
id | nome_cliente | sobrenome_cliente | etc..

tabela: Moderador
id | nome_moderador | cargo | etc..

tabela: Ticket
id | id_cliente | id_moderador | id_assunto  | etc..
```

Eu poderia apenas criar uma nova coluna `arquivado` na tabela `Ticket` e usar um `SQL` que selecione todos menos os arquivados. Mas ainda assim eles estariam registrados naquela tabela.

Criar uma nova tabela duplicada da tabela Ticket seria a solução? Ex.: `ticket_arquivos` e ai mover os registros para ela?

Ou qual outro método posso utilizar para fazer esse gerenciamento?

---

Outra dúvida em relação a isso seria quanto a identificação desses dados obsoletos. Atualmente possuo a coluna `status` e `data_update`, onde o status deve ser encerrado e a data atual deve ser maior que 15 dias da data de update. É possível fazer com que essa coluna `data_update` atualize automaticamente independente do tipo de `sql` que ela sofre? Seja um `UPDATE` ou um `SELECT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, creio que a melhor solução seja realmente criar uma tabela que receba esses registros "obsoletos".

Você poderia criar um *job* (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html) que seja executado periodicamente e que será o responsável por criar os registros na tabela de arquivo e excluir da tabela original.

Exemplo de *job* (ou *event*, como é chamado no **MySQL**):

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT e_arquivamento_diario
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    COMMENT 'Transfere registros obsoletos para tabela de arquivamento'
    DO
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO meu_esquema.meu_arquivo (col1, col2, col3)
          SELECT col1, col2, col3
            FROM meu_esquema.minha_tabela
           WHERE status = 'encerrado'
             AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), data_update) >= 15;

         // aqui também adicionar código de exclusão da tabela original

      END |

delimiter ;
```

Quanto a manutenção da coluna `data_update` você pode usar uma *trigger* (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) para atualizar seu valor em operações de `INSERT` e `UPDATE`, porém **não há tal dispositivo para controlar o acesso ao registro via `SELECT`**. Creio que neste caso teria que ser feito controle via sistema.

Uma *trigger* é disparada quando uma operação de `INSERT`, `UPDATE` ou `DELETE` é executada numa tabela. O código alocado na *trigger* pode ser executado antes (***BEFORE***) ou depois (***AFTER***) do comando da operação original.

Exemplo de *trigger* que será executada antes do `INSERT`, para preencher o valor de uma determinada coluna:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_data_update BEFORE INSERT ON minha_tabela
   FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.data_update = CURDATE();
```

*Trigger* para `UPDATE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_data_update BEFORE UPDATE ON minha_tabela
   FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.data_update = CURDATE();
```

Obs.: os valores, nomes de tabelas e colunas dos exemplos são apenas ilustrativos, devendo ser substituídos por valores e nomes reais para execução em ambiente de produção.

Comment: Apenas movendo para uma nova `tabela` já resolveria o caso de performance (pensando a longo prazo)? Ou seria necessário mover para outro banco (com uma estrutura copiada também)? Lendo alguns materiais depois da sua resposta vi que alguns tinham um banco a parte.

Comment: Sobre usar outro banco o não você deve levar em consideração se vai voltar a acessar esses dados com frequência. Se ainda vai ser possível realizar consultas, emitir relatórios, fica mais simples deixar tudo no mesmo banco. Se os dados ficarão simplesmente arquivados e serão acessados esporadicamente, então vale a pena deixar num outro banco. Quanto a performance, pensando em tempo de execução da query, creio que já resolveria, pois estaria executando a consulta na tabela sem o excesso de registros. Já quanto ao tamanho do banco e questão de armazenamento, não saberia te dizer.

Comment: Certo, era o que eu imaginava. A resposta está ok, mas você conseguiria elaborar um exemplo dos códigos citados, pelo menos do trigger junto a um update ou como seria um junto a um select, por exemplo.

Comment: Resposta alterada com exemplos, verifique.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado pela ajuda.